# Regular expression to allow only some characters in .net

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I was just working on some validation and was stuck up on this though :( I want a text which contains only [a-z][A-Z][0-9][_]  .

**It should accept any of the above characters any number of times in any order. All other characters marks the text as invalid.** 
I tried this but it is not working !!

```
  {
        ......

        Regex strPattern = new Regex("[0-9]*[A-Z]*[a-z]*[_]*");

        if (!strPattern.IsMatch(val))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true
  }
```

Comment: You should note `^\w*$` would validate the string for alphanumerics and underscores.

Comment: hey guys, I would like a pattern that must either be entirely numeric or begin with a single letter then followed by numbers.  In addition, the letters must be one of the following:
c, f, t, p, i or n.  I know there are other ways to validate this but I'm thinking a regex is the elegant way to go :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want this:

```
Regex strPattern = new Regex("^[0-9A-Za-z_]*$");
```

Your expression does not work because:

- It will accept any number of digits, followed by any number of uppercase letters, followed by any number of lowercase letters, followed by any number of underscores.  For example, an underscore followed by a number would not match.
- Your pattern is not anchored using the `^` and `$` characters.  This means that **every** string will match, because **every string contains zero or more of the specified characters**.  (For example, the string "!@#$" contains zero numbers, etc.!)  Anchoring the expression to the start and end of the string means that the *entire string* much match the *entire expression* or the match will fail.
- This pattern will still accept a zero-length string as valid.  If you would like to enforce that the string be at least one character, change the `*` near the end of the expression to `+`.  (`*` means "0 or more of the previous token" while `+` means "1 or more of the previous token.")

Comment: This would also match an empty string though, changing it slightly to  ^[0-9A-Za-z_]+$ would probably be better.

Comment: @miket2e: Perhaps, but the OP has not indicated that this is the case and I cannot determine from the question whether this is the intended behavior of the expression.  But I will edit my answer to introduce this possibility.

Comment: @miket2e - I needed the condition of empty string also !! Thanks for mentioning it. ( I should have framed question properly though !! )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new Regex("[0-9A-Za-z_]*");
```

Comment: Just FYI, this pattern will match every string.  In other words, there is no string for which `Regex.IsMatch()` would return false with this pattern.